# Warning for 'exhaustive-deps' keeps asking for the full 'props' object instead of allowing single 'props' methods as dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

This question is related to the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`

When I'm in CodeSanbox using a React Sandbox I can use single properties of the props object as dependencies for the useEffect hook:

Example 1:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('Running useEffect...');
  console.log(typeof(props.myProp));    // USING ONLY 'myProp' PROPERTY
},[ ]);                                 // EMPTY ARRAY
```

The example 1 gives me the following **warning** in CodeSandbox environment:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.myProp'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) eslint

And if I add `[props.myProp]` to the array, the warning goes away.

But the same example 1 in my local environment in VSCode, I get the following **warning**:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when any prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Is asks me that I'm missing the full `props` object. And if I add `[props.myProp]` to the array, **the warning DOES NOT go away.** Although the code works as intended.

I would expect that I would get the same behavior that I get on CodeSandbox in my local environment in VSCode.

What could be happening? Is there any configuration I could change in `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` ?

**PACKAGES**

DEV:

```
"eslint": "^5.10.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
```

REGULAR

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "root"  :true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors"
  ],
  "parser":"babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx":true
    }
  },
  "plugins":[
    "react",
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "semi": "error",
    "no-console": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver" : {
      "alias" : {
        "map" : [
          ["@components","./src/components"],
          ["@constants","./src/constants"],
          ["@helpers","./src/helpers"]
        ],
        "extensions": [".js"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is somewhat answered here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16265#issuecomment-517518539

> The reason plugin sees it differently is because by doing `props.whatever()` you are actually passing `props` itself as a `this` value to `whatever`. So technically it would see stale props.
>
> By reading the function before the call you’re avoiding the problem.

Although the answer says that destructuring is the answer, there is a small caveat. Destructuring or reassigning will either have no effect except resolving the warning (99% of cases) or break your code. If you destructure or reassign, the function will have no `this`, and if that's not a problem then the warning was meaningless. Here's a demo of a contrived case where any of this matters.

```
function bark() {
  console.log(`${this.name} barked.`);
}

const mac = {
  name: "mac",
  bark
};

const cheese = {
  name: "cheese",
  bark
};

const DogBark = props => {
  useEffect(() => props.dog.bark(), [props.dog.bark]);

  return null;
};

const Dog = () => {
  const [dog, setDog] = React.useState(mac);

  useEffect(() => setDog(cheese), []);

  // will cheese bark?
  return (
    <DogBark dog={dog} />
  );
};
```

Cheese will not bark. The problem becomes worse when you start using `useCallback`:

```
const DogBarkByCallback = props => {
  const bark = React.useCallback(() => props.dog.bark(), [props.dog.bark]);
  // every dog should bark, and if the definition of 
  // bark changes even though the dog is the same, it should bark again
  useEffect(() => bark(), [props.dog, bark]); 

  return null;
};
```

In this case, mac barks twice because the callback doesn't change. Thus, the solution is either to make sure `[props.dog]` is in your dependency array, as the warning recommends, or to know you don't need `this` and destructure or reassign the value to circumvent the warning.

Demonstrated here in the console: https://codesandbox.io/s/exhaustive-deps-fn-mrdld

Comment: Thanks John. I opened that issue. Right now I'm using an auxiliary variable to assign the method to, so I don't call it directly and the linter doesn't give any warnings. Like `const aux = props.method;`. I rarely rely on the `this` keyword in my code, so I haven't had any issues with that, but it's good to know that it might break things. It's not exactly a bug, but there are other people being "bugged" by this warning, as you could see on the Github issue.

Comment: I just came across this question, and figured it didn't have a really thorough answer and wanted to clarify some points. Hope it helped! I just made some small edits to clarify language.